# Difficult Deserialize Method IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, deserialization

I wrote a program that does work with files like delete and update, store, and search And all customers,Employee and Order...

But my problem is with the deserialize method u know when it's called i get this error :

**IndexOutOfRangeException**

I've tried the Try Catch method but it makes the program slow n decreases its efficiency

[**Project Files**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bq5ilytvwsef1zj/CoustomersApp6.rar)

[**Video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UrgZY7BcrY&feature=youtu.be)

```
   public T Deserialize<T>(string entity)
    {
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        var stringProps = entity.Split(',');
        var objProps = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

        var propIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < stringProps.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (objProps[propIndex].PropertyType.FullName == "System.String")
                {
                    objProps[propIndex].SetValue(obj, stringProps[i], null);
                }

                else if (objProps[propIndex].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Int32")
                {
                    objProps[propIndex].SetValue(obj, Convert.ToInt32(stringProps[i]), null);
                }
                else if (objProps[propIndex].PropertyType.FullName == "System.DateTime")
                {
                    var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
                    DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(stringProps[i], cultureInfo);
                    objProps[propIndex].SetValue(obj, dateTime, null);
                }
                else if (objProps[propIndex].PropertyType.FullName == "System.boolean")
                {
                    objProps[propIndex].SetValue(obj, Convert.ToBoolean(stringProps[i]), null);
                }

                else
                {
                    i--;
                }
                propIndex++;
            }

            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Index Out Of range");
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: So what's your question? Do you want to fix your program so that it works and no longer throws that exception? Or are you okay with the exception and just want to handle it more efficiently? If the latter, then you can just have an empty `catch`. I suspect, though, that you have a logic error and you need to fix that.

Comment: yes want to fix your program so that it works and no longer throws that exception.

Comment: Edit your question. Show an example class that you want to initialize, and show an example of the data that you're trying to deserialize. Show a class definition and the contents of the `stringProps` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a function(deletespace) that has the task of removing spaces in the string and the problem was solved with this method.

```
 public T Deserialize<T>(string entity)
    {
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        var stringProps = entity.Split(',');
        **var str = deletespace(stringProps);**
        var objProps = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

        var propIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (objProps[propIndex].PropertyType.FullName == "System.String")
                {
                    objProps[propIndex].SetValue(obj, stringProps[i], null);
                }

                else if (objProps[propIndex].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Int32")
                {
                    objProps[propIndex].SetValue(obj, Convert.ToInt32(stringProps[i]), null);
                }
                else if (objProps[propIndex].PropertyType.FullName == "System.DateTime")
                {
                    var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
                    DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(stringProps[i], cultureInfo);
                    objProps[propIndex].SetValue(obj, dateTime, null);
                }
                else if (objProps[propIndex].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Boolean")
                {
                    objProps[propIndex].SetValue(obj, Convert.ToBoolean(stringProps[i]), null);
                }

                else
                {
                    i--;
                }
                propIndex++;
            }

            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Index Out Of range");
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }

    **private List<string> deletespace(string[] spaceStrings)
    {
        var lststr = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < spaceStrings.Length; i++)
        {
            if (spaceStrings[i] != "")
            {
                lststr.Add(spaceStrings[i]);
            }
        }
        return lststr;
    }**
```

Comment: Rather than that, you could have written `var stringProps = entity.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` See [String.Split method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You missed to check wether your `propIndex` is in range of your `objProps` array.

You could make following change to your code:

```
for (int i = 0;
     i < stringProps.Length - 1 
         && propIndex < objProps.Length - 1; // <-- check wether you're in range
     i++)
```

Another way would be to put the try catch block outside the for loop, so that you are not iterating over any more `stringProps` when the `IndexOutOfRangeException` starts to occur.

This way you keep the error logging.

Comment: That avoids the error, but it doesn't make the program work. It appears that the OP has a fundamental misunderstanding of how to do what he wants to do.

Comment: Right, but what he originally wanted to gain is not known. Sure he has to implement a kind of error handling, as best in the catch clause.